# R plot is missing a line that I think it should have

Tags: r

When I try this:

```
fitBlack=dim(501)
fitWhite=dim(501)
ag=dim(501)
for (i in 1:501) {
ag[i]=(99+i)/100
fitBlack[i]=exp(m1$coef[1]+ag[i]*m1$coef[3])/(1+exp(m1$coef[1]+
ag[i]*m1$coef[3]))
fitWhite[i]=exp(m1$coef[1]+m1$coef[2]+ag[i]*m1$coef[3])/
(1+exp(m1$coef[1]+m1$coef[2]+ag[i]*m1$coef[3]))
}
plot(fitBlack~ag,type="l",col="black",ylab="Prob[Death]",
xlab="Aggravation",ylim=c(0,1),
main="red line for white victim; black line for black victim")
points(fitWhite~ag,type="l",col="red")
```

It gives me the black line fine, but it is missing the red line, and I don't know what I'm missing as the method for this came from a textbook.

Comment: Can you post the data in `m1`?

Comment: @Werner
```
Call:  glm(formula = Death ~ VRace + Agg, family = binomial, data = don)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        VRace          Agg  
     -6.676        1.811        1.540  

Degrees of Freedom: 361 Total (i.e. Null);  359 Residual
Null Deviance:      321.9 
Residual Deviance: 113.5        AIC: 119.5
> ```

Comment: @justmayo please edit your above post and include the output of `dput(m1)`